# Is it possible to delay video play on iOS safari?

Tags: ios, video, safari, autoplay

As we all know, iOS safari can not use js to control video play with non-mute.

But I want to delay the action of playing after pressing the button. Before pressing the play button, play a h5 animation first, about 3 secs, and then start playing the video after the animation. Is this possible?

I tried to set `volume=0.01` when pressing the play button, and then set'currentTime=0' to play from the beginning after animation finished, but `volume` cannot be used on iOS safari, so is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I found another way, it works

```
onPlayClick() {
  this.revideo.muted = false;
  this.revideo.volume = 1;
  this.revideo.autoplay = true;
  this.revideo.play();

  this.muteInterval = setInterval(() => {
    this.revideo.currentTime = 0;
  }, 10);

  setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(this.muteInterval);
  }, 3000);
}
```